# Issue publishing and installing standalone schematic package to Angular project

Tags: angular, npm, angular-schematics

My goal is to publish a custom Angular schematic package to my company's private npm registry for other devs to leverage. Here's what I've accomplished so far:

- Created separate schematic project using schematic CLI.
- Verified the schematic works locally in an Angular project via `npm link`.
- Built and published the schematic project to the company registry.

When I try to `npm install` from the registry, I end up running into errors. First, there's a permissions warning on missing write access to the corresponding `node_modules` subfolder, and then npm eventually fails with `ENOENT: No such file or directory` for the same folder.

I'm unable to figure out what I missed. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `node_modules` addressed the issue. There must've been artifacts leftover from the previous link.